# How to calculate the eigenvalues/pseudo-determinant of a finite difference gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

**Question in short**

Is there an analytical solution for the (non-zero) eigenvalues/pseudo-determinant, i.e., the product of all non-zero eigenvalues, of the real, symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix

$$\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}\mathbf{D}_{m}$$

where $\mathbf{D}_{m}$ is a [finite forward difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient#Forward_finite_difference) matrix?
With $\mathbf{D}_{m}$, the $m$-th order forward difference of a signal $\mathbf{y}$ of size $n$ can be computed as $\mathbf{D}_{m}\mathbf{y}$. 
$\mathbf{D}_{m}$ is of shape $\left(n-m\right) \times m$ and $\mathbf{P}$ has $n-m$ non-zero eigenvalues as obvious from the description of $\mathbf{D}_{m}$ below.

**Background**

I'm trying to implement the Whittaker-Henderson smoother that selects its own smoothing parameter by maximising the marginal likelihood as described by

Biessy G., et al.: *Revisiting Whittaker-Henderson Smoothing*, 2023, [link to arXiv](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2306.06932),
Chapter (Sections 5 and 5.1, **pp. 17-20**)

In this specific problem, the [pseudo-determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant) needs to be computed for the penalty matrix $\mathbf{P}$ as $\ln\left|\mathbf{P}\right|_{+}$. Of course, from a practical point of view, the logarithms of all non-zero eigenvalues should be summed for this.
$\mathbf{P}$ is the Gram product of an $m$-th order finite forward difference matrix $\mathbf{D}_{m}$ (the accuracy as named in the Wikipedia articile is 1). So,

$$\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}\mathbf{D}_{m}$$

where, e.g.,

$$\mathbf{D}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{D}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
1&-2&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&-2&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&-2&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&-2&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

for obtaining the finite forward differences of a signal $\mathbf{y}$ of size $n=6$. Only rows with full coefficients are used, leaving a shape of $\left(n-m\right) \times n$.
In this context, $m$ can go much higher, e.g., for spatially adaptive smoothing that involves the 6-th order difference for obtaining a smooth estimate of the 4-th order derivative via the Whittaker-Henderson smoother.

Given all this, it is easy to obtain that $\mathbf{P}$ is a real, symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix with $n-m$ non-zero eigenvalues.

**Problem**

I'm struggling to find an efficient and accurate way to obtain the log-pseudo-determinant $\ln\left|\mathbf{P}\right|_{+}$, especially for higher orders of $m$ and large signal sizes $n$ because the computation time increases dramatically for $n > 1000$ and for $m > 4$ the ratio between the smallest non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda_{\min.}^{+}$ and the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max.}$ exceeds $10^{15}$ already for $n < 1000$, thereby causing $\lambda_{\min.}^{+}$ and its closest neighbours to be possibly slightly negative since they are computed from 64-bit-float numbers. This prohibits the computation of $\ln\left|\mathbf{P}\right|_{+}$ since then it is impossible to sum the logarithms of the eigenvalues if only one goes negative as its presence in $\ln\left|\mathbf{P}\right|_{+}$ is crucial despite its magnitude.
I was thus thinking that an analytical solution (or even a crude approximation only) for the eigenvalues/log-pseudo-determinant would

1. be cheaper to compute
2. not suffer as much from floating point inaccuracies since the eigenvalues are not originating form a cascade of operations on the same matrix.

**What I tried so far**

First, I was tackling the problem numerically using a dense eigenvalue solver which seems to suffer less from floating point precision, but cannot be scaled to large $n > 2500$ as it takes more than 10 seconds to compute (Python NumPy Hermitian Eigensolver which relies on LAPACK).
Afterwards, I tried another dense solver which is faster, but apparently at the expense of precision causing negative eigenvalues for $m=4$ at $n > 1000$ ([Python SciPy Hermitian Eigensolver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvalsh.html) with also relies on LAPACK, called with “evr” driver).
From looking at the [R-implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeBiessy/WH/blob/master/R/tools.R#L38-L67) of the original publication named above, it is apparent that a dense solver was used without any special measures against floating point imprecision.
Then - since $\mathbf{P}$ is banded with $m$ off-diagonals on each side - I tried to use an Eigensolver for Hermitian Banded Matrices which relies on a divide and conquer algorithm. This proved to be more than twice as fast as the dense solvers, but also gave negative eigenvalues for $m=4$ and $n > 800$ ([Python SciPy Hermitian Banded Eigensolver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvals_banded.html)).
Finally, I tried to follow the Wikipedia article on the [eigendecomposition of the second order derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Derivation_of_Eigenvalues_and_Eigenvectors_in_the_Discrete_Case) with different boundary conditions because I found that this is closest to the problem at hand from all online sources I dug into. That's where I'm stuck because I don't find a way to re-phrase $\mathbf{P}$ with arbitrary $m$ to match this approach - if this is possible at all.

**Alternative Solutions**

As mentioned above, a crude approximation of the eigenvalues or the log-pseudo-determinant would probably be a huge step forward.
Otherwise, it could maybe also be beneficial to re-think the boundary conditions of $\mathbf{D}_{m}$ as long as they are not periodic. I was thinking about a mirrored ($d c b \left| a b c d e f g \right| f e d$) or repeating boundary ($a a a \left| a b c d e f g \right| g g g$).

**Related Questions**

There is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755113/1261538) that deals with higher *order* finite difference matrix eigendecomposition, but this refers to different *accuracies* and not *orders* if the naming from the Wikipedia article on finite differences is applied.

Thanks very much for any answers and comments!
Note: I'm familiar with basic linear algebra, but not a professional and thus not that used to all mathematical abbreviations and symbols

Comment: at a minimum you get some improvements if you focus on $\mathbf{P}' = \mathbf{D}_{m}\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}$ which is PD, hence you don't need to talk about pseudo-determinants

Comment: @user8675309 thanks for the quick reply! You're absolutely correct! I will try to see if I can compute the banded Cholesky decomposition $\mathbf{P'}=\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^T$. From this, the determinant is more easy to infer given that the main diagonal elements don't suffer from floating point inaccuracies. I will probably have to implement it from scratch using more accurate algorithms for computing the sums of float numbers and also properly handling all the multiplications and square-roots.

Comment: I would typically guess that running 'thin' QR factorization on $\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}$ would be preferable from a stability and number of computations standpoint.  You still recover Cholesky as $\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T} = QR$ where $R$ is invertible, so $LL^T =\mathbf{D}_{m}\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}= R^TR$

Comment: Would adding a small multiple of the identity matrix help, i.e., $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}\mathbf{D_{m}}+\mu\mathbf{I}$? To ensure that systems are numerically PD, I determine $\lambda_{\max}$ using a sparse eigensolver (ARPACK in SciPy) and  $\lambda_{\min}$ using the same solver, but with shift-invert method close to a small negative number computed from the matrix size. Then, I calculate $\mu$ so that $\frac{\lambda_{\min}+\mu}{\lambda_{\max} + \mu}$ is g.e. a small number like $10^{-13\dots15}$. I know this messes with the determinant, but the smoothing should still be satisfactory.

Comment: From a smoothing perspective, it would just change the prior from this derivative-based Tikhonov regularization with $\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}\mathbf{D}$ to a combined Tikhonov regularization with prior $\mathbf{D}_{m}^{T}\mathbf{D}+\mu\mathbf{I}$ where $\mu\mathbf{I}$ is the fraction of "ordinary" Tikhonov-regularisation contributing to the prior.